# Wordpress is blocking my jquery script

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, hidden

**Script Noob Disclaimer**

On my website I want it to add fields to the contact form to act as line items for my product but for some reason wordpress isn't allowing my functions to work. Here's what it is suppose to do http://jsfiddle.net/LQ85Z/1/ and here's how my site is handling it http://ocblinds.com/order-now/. My website isn't allowing the divs to be shown. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
$('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').hide();
        $('#line_3').hide();
        $('#line_4').hide();
        $('#line_5').hide();
        $('#line_6').hide();
        $('#line_7').hide();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();

        }
    });
});
$(function() {
$('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "2") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').hide();
        $('#line_4').hide();
        $('#line_5').hide();
        $('#line_6').hide();
        $('#line_7').hide();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "3") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').hide();
        $('#line_5').hide();
        $('#line_6').hide();
        $('#line_7').hide();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();

        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "4") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').hide();
        $('#line_6').hide();
        $('#line_7').hide();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "5") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').show();
        $('#line_6').hide();
        $('#line_7').hide();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "6") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').show();
        $('#line_6').show();
        $('#line_7').hide();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "7") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').show();
        $('#line_6').show();
        $('#line_7').show();
        $('#line_8').hide();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "8") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').show();
        $('#line_6').show();
        $('#line_7').show();
        $('#line_8').show();
        $('#line_9').hide();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "9") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').show();
        $('#line_6').show();
        $('#line_7').show();
        $('#line_8').show();
        $('#line_9').show();
        $('#line_10').hide();
        }
        });
    });
        $(function() {
        $('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "10") {
        $('#line_1').show();
        $('#line_2').show();
        $('#line_3').show();
        $('#line_4').show();
        $('#line_5').show();
        $('#line_6').show();
        $('#line_7').show();
        $('#line_8').show();
        $('#line_9').show();
        $('#line_10').show();
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have comes from the fact that you have an illegal character embedded at the bottom of your orderform.js script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "10") {
            $('#line_1').show();
            $('#line_2').show();
            $('#line_3').show();
            $('#line_4').show();
            $('#line_5').show();
            $('#line_6').show();
            $('#line_7').show();
            $('#line_8').show();
            $('#line_9').show();
            $('#line_10').show();
        }
    });
});â€‹
```

Remove it and it will work fine.

You also seem to have embedded your javascript code inside the page itself (it's present in both the page source AND orderform.js). Remove the duplicate that's in the source code, especially that it also contains illegal characters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $('#line_1').show();
            $('#line_2').hide();
            $('#line_3').hide();
            $('#line_4').hide();
            $('#line_5').hide();
            $('#line_6').hide();
            $('#line_7').hide();
            $('#line_8').hide();
            $('#line_9').hide();
            $('#line_10').hide();</p>
<p>        }
    });
});
```

(Notice <**/p**> and <**p**>)

You can also optimize your code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
        var i, show = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        for (i = 1; i <= show; i++) {
            $('#line_' + i).show();
        }
        for (i = show; i < 10; i++) {
            $('#line_' + i).hide();
        }  
    });
});
```

or by using the other answer to your question (more elegant).

Comment: Wow that optimization is going to save me a lot of time down the road. But, I can't figure out what's giving me that illegal character. If you download orderform.js it doesn't show it an any reader or editor. I have to assume it's either wordpress or my host

Comment: It's the encoding of your file that's at fault.

Comment: Have a look here, where you can clearly see that character: http://ocblinds.com/wp-content/themes/Agivee/js/orderform.js

Comment: Wo had no idea how much encoding mattered. I just used notepad instead of dreamweaver and puff it worked. Thank you very much. I'll be spending the next hour or so making it look pretty now.

Comment: Check my revised answer to see another problem (duplicated code). Also, I'm pretty sure I'm the person who actually answered your question as to why it didn't work, contrary to which answer you actually picked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress runs jQuery in no-conflict mode, so it isn't globally available as `$`. The following method will allow you to use `$` on `.ready()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // Put your scripting here...
});
```